# Boost Log Callback

Tags: boost, boost-log

I have created a logger mechanism based on [Boost Log](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/index.html).

My code is based on the trivial logger as shown in this [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_trivial_flt.cpp).

I was wondering how to automatically call system exit

```
exit(1)
```

(or any other custom callback function) whenever a fatal error occurs.

Any help is welcomed!

**UPDATE:**

The solution is to [extend the backend sink](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0_beta1/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension.html#log.extension.sinks) by overloading the `consume()` method.

Comment: You could write your own [`boost::log` sink](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/extension.html#log.extension.sinks).  But logging and error handling are separate concerns and you probably shouldn't mix them.  In addition, calling `exit()` is an inelegant way to terminate a c++ program as RAII objects won't be released.  When you encounter a fatal condition, what's wrong with logging it and throwing an exception?

Comment: You are right, I do have my custom sinks and `exit(1)` is not elegant. It just happens in my mind/implementation a `LOG(FATAL)` to act as a process terminating exception and I thought they could be "unified".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example of a sink examining the severity level of the trivial logger:

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/basic_sink_backend.hpp>
#include <boost/log/attributes/value_extraction.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sinks/async_frontend.hpp>
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;

void initBoostLog() {
  struct Sink: public sinks::basic_formatted_sink_backend<char, sinks::concurrent_feeding> {
    void consume (const boost::log::record_view& rec, const string& str) {
      using boost::log::trivial::severity_level;
      auto severity = rec.attribute_values()[boost::log::aux::default_attribute_names::severity()].extract<severity_level>();
      if (!severity || severity.get() <= severity_level::info) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
      } else {
        std::cerr << str << std::endl;
      }
    }
  };

  typedef sinks::asynchronous_sink<Sink> sink_t; boost::shared_ptr<sink_t> sink (new sink_t());
  boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::core> logc = boost::log::core::get();
  logc->add_sink (sink);
}
```

Comment: Is `consume()` called automatically? Because it does not seem to do so. It compiles showing a warning that the paren boost method is now shadowed. I am not sure if the fact that i use synchronous sinks matters.